# why using var {google} instead of var google in google.auth.OAuth

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

This code is from oauth nodesjs.
I want to ask why we are using '{}' around the var google? I also tried using it without '{}' and got error OAuth2 is undefined. i can't understand what is happening here.

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a little to this answer - this is what's called a *destructuring assignment*.  You can read about them here:

http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html

The code you're looking at here:

`const {google} = require('googleapis');`

Is the same as code that looks like this:

`const google = require('googleapis').google;`

This is just a convenient shorthand that was added in es6.  We made the change in the googleapis package when we moved towards ES modules, which don't play nicely with the `export=foo` style syntax.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Changelog from google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/releases/tag/v26.0.0), there are some changes from **V26.0.0 onwards** that you have to implement in your code, precisely the issue you are experiencing is mentioned. I also took a while to figure this one out...

> BREAKING CHANGE: This library is now optimized for es6 modules. In previous versions you would import the library like this:

```
const google = require('googleapis');
```

> In this and future versions, you must use a named import:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
```

> You may also reference the type to instantiate a new instance:

```
const {GoogleApis} = require('googleapis');
const google = new GoogleApis();
```